# Difference between two array printing methods in bash

Tags: bash, array, echo, bash-array

I have an array declared in my script.

```
NAME[0]=Deepak
NAME[1]=Renuka
NAME[2]=Joe
NAME[3]=Alex
NAME[4]=Amir

echo "All Index: ${NAME[*]}"
echo "All Index: ${NAME[@]}"
```

There are two ways to print whole array which is shown above. Can some please write the difference between those methods?

Comment: Why did you post a picture of text?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `echo "All Index: ${NAME[*]}"` equals to `echo "All Index: ${NAME[0]} ${NAME[1]} ${NAME[2]} ${NAME[3]} ${NAME[4]}"`
- `echo "All Index: ${NAME[@]}"` equals to `echo "All Index: ${NAME[0]}" "${NAME[1]}" "${NAME[2]}" "${NAME[3]}" "${NAME[4]}"` if the first character of `IFS` variable is a space (default)

You can see the execution result in [copy.sh](https://copy.sh/v86/?profile=archlinux&c=set%20-x%3B%20NAME%5B0%5D%3D%22Deepak%22%3B%20NAME%5B1%5D%3D%22Renuka%22%3B%20NAME%5B2%5D%3D%22Joe%22%3B%20NAME%5B3%5D%3D%22Alex%22%3B%20NAME%5B4%5D%3D%22Amir%22%3B%20echo%20%22All%20Index%3A%20%24%7BNAME%5B*%5D%7D%22%3B%20echo%20%22All%20Index%3A%20%24%7BNAME%5B%40%5D%7D%22).

---

The default value of `IFS` variable is `$' \t\n'`.
`${array[*]}` and `$*` output strings splited by the first character of `IFS` variable.
It is also possible to change the character to split.

```bsh
NAME[0]=Deepak
NAME[1]=Renuka
NAME[2]=Joe
NAME[3]=Alex
NAME[4]=Amir

IFS=:
echo "All Index: ${NAME[*]}"
# Output: `All Index: Deepak:Renuka:Joe:Alex:Amir`

IFS=
echo "All Index: ${NAME[*]}"
# Output: `All Index: DeepakRenukaJoeAlexAmir`

IFS=$', \t\n'
echo "All Index: ${NAME[*]}"
# Output: `All Index: Deepak,Renuka,Joe,Alex,Amir`
```